# db2iupdt ERROR: The specified instance "instance_name" does not exist

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to run the `db2iupdt` command on my database, however I am hitting the following command:

```
The specified instance "db2inst1" does not exist. Specify an existing instance
name.
```

I trying to refer to https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2iupdt-error-specified-instance-instancename-does-not-exist , but I do not have duplicate `global.reg` file.

I still can see my instance after I run `db2ilist` command.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: What's the result of the following commands from root?
`/usr/local/bin/db2ls`, 
`$(/usr/local/bin/db2ls | awk 'NR==4 {print $1}')/bin/db2greg -dump`, 
`$(/usr/local/bin/db2ls | awk 'NR==4 {print $1}')/bin/db2greg -getinstrec instancename=db2inst1`, 
`su - db2inst1 -c "db2gcf -s"`

Answer (score 0):

If I logon as instance owner db2inst1 and run:

```
$ mv sqllib sqllib.bk
```

Then logon as root and run:

```
# /opt/ibm/db2/instance/db2iupdt db2inst1
# /opt/ibm/db2/instance/db2ilist
```

Got the same situation, db2iupdt returns **"db2inst1" does not exist** and db2ilist lists up **db2inst1**.

So it is suggested to check the instance home directory's sqllib exist or not.
If the sqllib exist, the instance may be corrupted somehow.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the variable of DB2INSTANCE in INSTDIR/sqllib/db2profile

```
cat db2profile | grep DB2INSTANCE
```